# Why after defining some method from object to variable context lost?

Tags: javascript, class-constructors

please help to get answer 
i can't understand why the context lost after defination

```js
    class A {
     func() {
      console.log(this)
     }
    }
    
    let a = new A();
    let b = a.func;
    b();
```

Comment: This is simply the intentional behavior for JS by default. If you'd like to preserve a function's context, there's the `bind` method available for that purpose. E.g. `let b = a.func.bind(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) in order to clarify your doubt.

Simple this short if you call a function on object javascript considers that object as its this/context.

eg.

```
let obj = {
   key : 'value',
   fun : function(){

   }
}
// if called like obj.fun() --> obj is going to be this
// if called like let ffun = obj.fun; ffun();  ---> window/global object is going to be this
```

If you call that method by using call/apply/bind you need to specify custom context as first parameter to these methods.

```
//if call like obj.fun.call(someObject, p1, p2)
// Or obj.fun.apply(someObject, [p1, p2])
// Or let ffun = obj.fun.bind(someObject, [p1, p2]);   ffun();
// someObject is going to be this in all these 3 cases
```

In otherwise cases where a function is directly called it takes window/global object as its context.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @junvar in comments you should bind function to `this`.
You can make it for example in the constructor :

```js
    class A {
        constructor(){
           this.func = this.func.bind(this)
        }
     func() {
      console.log(this)
     }
    }
    
    let a = new A();
    let b = a.func;
    b();
```